# RefreshAll trava a execução do VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Olá, procurei mas não achei algo semelhante ao meu problema.
Trabalho em uma empresa onde temos alguns relatórios, em um terminal remoto, que possuem consultas a bancos de dados, após realizada a consulta sempre inserimos um `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` para atualizar as tabelas dinâmicas e Consultas de Dados Externos que possam existir. Funcionava muito bem.

Questão é que algum tempo para cá a demora para executar o código ficou grande e até travar o Excel, após uma análise descobrimos que o comando `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` está travando sempre a execução e após retirar de todos os arquivos as consultas voltaram ao normal.

Queria saber se alguém já teve problema parecido e como resolveu?
Porque agora os usuários precisam atualizar as tabelas dinâmicas manualmente e o problema maior é que se eu tiver uma Consulta de Dados Externa de apoio ela também não se atualiza.

Answer (score 0):

Suave?

Eu não sei quantas tabelas dinâmicas a sua planilha tem, mas uma possibilidade é nomear no código a lista de tabelas dinâmicas a serem atualizadas. Por exemplo:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica1").PivotCache.Refresh
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica2").PivotCache.Refresh
```

Assim, a planilha atualiza apenas as tabelas mapeadas, ao invés de todos os intervalos de dados externos e relatórios de tabela dinâmica da planilha, que é o que o `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` faz e pode demorar muito para processar.

Se não ajudar ou você precisar de mais informações, me avise.

Comment: Então até pensei em fazer isso mas a quantidade de tabelas dinâmicas e consultas são grande e em vários arquivos, teria que fazer em todos.